# Missing buttons for “Merge changes in merge tool”, “Take server version” etc. in VStudio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

Latest Visual Studio 2019, buttons for “Merge changes in merge tool”, “Take server version” etc. are missing. We use Team Foundation Server as source control.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/499815/merge-tools-in-resolve-conflicts-not-shown.html

Should I really install an older version of Visual Studio or somebody found a workaround for this issue?

Comment: Good point Daniel, to me this issue is comparable to BMW selling cars without a door and only a few customers complain. Resolving conflicts is a critical task and I cannot believe that nobody is using it in VStudio 2019. I'm trying to figure out how the rest of VStudio 2019 users bypassed this bug

Comment: There are there 3 possible workarounds:

1) Closing and re-opening Visual Studio.

2)Update to version 16.03.

3) 1- "Repairing" the installation via the Visual Studio Installer, and then 2- disabling the GitHub extension. Not entirely sure step 2 was required.

Comment: VStudio 16.0.4 installed. None of the workarounds worked for me.

Comment: look in the thread, there is a new temporary workaround :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in later Visual Studio 2019 updates.